# Page load Problem

Tags: firefox-addon

My web page is not loading properly.How to debug this problem?Is there any addon on mozilla for this?

Comment: Define "not loading properly."  Do you get an error?  Does specific content not render?  Does specific styling/scripting not apply?  How are you accessing the page?  Where is it located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you need to test you can get away with Firebug - for example XUL page without much XBL.

If you need to test some chrome JavaScript you might use Chromebug: http://getfirebug.com/releases/chromebug/

If Firebug nor Chromebug can help you can try JavaScript Debugger aka Venkman: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/216/

Venkman is probably most powerful but not the friendliest one.
Also, if nothing else helps you can use alerts.

Answer (score 1):

It is a static web page, or you have a backend with a specific language?

You can try use **firebug** to figure out the problems, but if you have an backend application, so you have to debug the app instead of the page.